# interfacing with executable JAR to manipulate Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar

I have a executable JAR which brings up a Swing GUI and, after some choices in select boxes and such and pressing an OK button, runs a process. I would like to automate the act of making these choices and running the process.

I don't have access to the source code or any documentation, so it seems to me like the only way to do this is to somehow connect to the GUI and simulate a user. A worst-case scenario is using a java.awt.Robot to actually manipulate the cursor to make the desired changes, but that is extremely messy and error-prone. Are there any better ways to interface with the GUI?

Comment: If the license allows it, you could decompile the program, read the source code, and see if you can write a program that utilizes their internal API to do what the GUI does, programmatically.

Comment: @Mike, you should write this up as an answer.  It is the "do-this-if-at-all-possible" solution.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, I assume you can load the jar into your own main() and invoke their GUI entry class.

Swing (like AWT) lets you introspect a GUI quite easily.  The GUI is probably a tree of panels and children.  Once you recurse through the tree and find the widget you want to invoke (that's the hard part), you can just click buttons, etc programmatically.

[going off on a tangent...]
I use this technique routinely for unit testing my own GUIs.  I make sure to call "setName()" on the components I plan to introspect and I depth-first recurse through my UI until "getName()" yields the string I'm looking for.  This lets me refactor the GUI without needing to change the test scaffolding very much.  The same concept can often apply to working with third-party GUIs, but alas they rarely use setName() so identifying components can be harder -- you need to look at the button text, etc.